# notifyDataSetChanged does not update my recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a `ArrayList` getting data from `IntentService`. After I got my data I updated my adapter and called `notifyDataSetChanged()`. But it does not change data.

Here is my code:

```
public class Nearby_ViewPager_Stations extends Fragment {

private View mRootView = null;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private StationsReceiver mStationsReciever;
private MKLoader mProgressBar;

private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private Context mContext;
ArrayList<ArrayList<StationArrivalPOJO>> stationArrivalPOJO = new ArrayList<>();

private static final String TAG = "NearbyViewPagerStations";

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (mRootView == null) {
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nearby_viewpager_stations, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mProgressBar = (MKLoader) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }

    mStationsReciever = new StationsReceiver(new Handler());
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new Adapter_recyclerView(stationArrivalPOJO);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startIntentService();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 20*1000);
        }
    }, 1000);
    return mRootView;
}

private void startIntentService() {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(mContext, GetAllStationsAndStopsIntentService.class);
    intent1.putExtra("Receiver", mStationsReciever);
    intent1.putExtra("latitude", Constants.latitude);
    intent1.putExtra("longitude", Constants.longitude);
    mContext.startService(intent1);
}

void addAdapter(ArrayList<ArrayList<StationArrivalPOJO>> resultData) {
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (stationArrivalPOJO.size() > 0)
        stationArrivalPOJO.clear();
    stationArrivalPOJO.addAll(resultData);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Log.v(TAG, "added all data: "+ stationArrivalPOJO.get(0).get(0).getTimeToStation());
}

public class StationsReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
    StationsReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);

        addAdapter((ArrayList<ArrayList<StationArrivalPOJO>>)resultData.getSerializable("StationPOJO"));
    }
}
```

}

And here is my Adapter code:

```
 class Adapter_recyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private ArrayList<ArrayList<StationArrivalPOJO>> mStationPojoList;
private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

private Context mContext;

private static final String TAG = "AdapterRecyclerView";

Adapter_recyclerView(ArrayList<ArrayList<StationArrivalPOJO>> data) {
    mStationPojoList = data;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ((ViewHolder)holder).stationNameTV.setText(mStationPojoList.get(position).get(0).getStationName());

    ArrayList<String> mUniqueStationName = new ArrayList<>();  //Unique platform names of a station got from hash set 'uniqStatNames'
    HashSet<String> uniqStatNames = new HashSet<>(); //Unique platform names of a station

    for (int i = 0;i<mStationPojoList.get(position).size(); i++) {
        uniqStatNames.add(mStationPojoList.get(position).get(i).getPlatformName()
        + mStationPojoList.get(position).get(i).getTowards());
    }

    for(Iterator<String> it = uniqStatNames.iterator() ; it.hasNext() ; ) {
        mUniqueStationName.add(it.next());
    }

    for (int j=0; j<mUniqueStationName.size(); j++) {
        ArrayList<StationArrivalPOJO> arrivalPOJOs = new ArrayList<>();   //Platform wise categorized train details
        for (int i = 0;i<mStationPojoList.get(position).size(); i++) {
            if (mUniqueStationName.get(j).contains(mStationPojoList.get(position).get(i).getPlatformName())
                    && mUniqueStationName.get(j).contains(mStationPojoList.get(position).get(i).getTowards())) {
                arrivalPOJOs.add(mStationPojoList.get(position).get(i));
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(arrivalPOJOs, new Comparator<StationArrivalPOJO>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(StationArrivalPOJO stationArrivalPOJO, StationArrivalPOJO t1) {
                return stationArrivalPOJO.getTimeToStation() - t1.getTimeToStation();
            }
        });

        for (int k=0; k<arrivalPOJOs.size(); k++) {
        Log.v(TAG, j+":"+mUniqueStationName.size()+"boo"+arrivalPOJOs.toString());
        Log.v(TAG, "boom " + arrivalPOJOs.get(k).getPlatformName() + ":" + arrivalPOJOs.get(k).getTowards());

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
        relativeLayout.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        TextView trainName = new TextView(mContext);
        trainName.setText(arrivalPOJOs.get(k).getPlatformName());

        TextView towards = new TextView(mContext);
        towards.setText(arrivalPOJOs.get(k).getTowards());

        linearLayout.addView(trainName);
        linearLayout.addView(towards);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);

        TextView time = new TextView(mContext);
        time.setText(String.valueOf(arrivalPOJOs.get(k).getTimeToStation()));

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        time.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);

        relativeLayout.addView(linearLayout);
        relativeLayout.addView(time);

        mLinearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);
        }}
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View rootView =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.adapter_recyclerview,parent,false);
    mContext = parent.getContext();

    mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cardViewLinearLayout);
    TextView mStationName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stationName);

    return new ViewHolder(rootView, mStationName);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mStationPojoList.size();
}

private static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView stationNameTV;

    ViewHolder(View view, TextView stationNameTV) {
        super(view);
        this.stationNameTV = stationNameTV;
    }
}
```

}

When I retrieve data from `ArrayList` and print in log station I get updated values. But that updates are not getting reflected in my recycler list.

I have seen other questions in Stack Overflow saying that:

1. we need update data from the same `Fragment` object
2. notifyDataSetChanged()` should be called from ui thread.

I dont understand what I am missing.

Comment: add your adapter's code

Comment: you are not sending new data to the adapter!

Comment: @Atef Hares I have called addAll() on ArrayList and then called notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter. Are these two lines not sufficient to update RecyclerView ?

Comment: Yes, I guess they are not, you should make sure that the data inside the adapter is updated, I mean you have to make sure that `mStationPojoList` from your adapter is updated before calling `notifyDataSetChanged() `, if you don't know how to update it, I can help!

Comment: @AtefHares Please let me know. I tried calling mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter) before calling notifyDataSetChanged(). Data is updating but RecyclerView is scrolling to the top again.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Have a look at this sample, in the ui package there is the adapter for a recycler view. The adapter is setup in FlagListFragment. https://github.com/AlexGoja/flag-application. So the idea is to have a setter for the data inside your adapter and call that setter once you have your data ready (i.e maybe coming from a rest api, etc.).

Comment: I think that you should rethink how your code should work. In `onBindViewHolder` you are sorting an array when that method is called leading to an increased probability of scrolling lag.

Comment: debug your code by adding dummy data and check each and every line is working or not because debuging is the only solution for this code !

Comment: there is **NO** need to re set `stationArrivalPOJO` in the adapter, the reference of `stationArrivalPOJO` is already passed in the adapter's constructor, and any action on `stationArrivalPOJO` will affect the adapter, ex `clear(), addAll()...` as long as you don't re instantiate `stationArrivalPOJO`, like `stationArrivalPOJO = new Array...` you are good, and your code is correct, you are having a problem somewhere else. as a prove, debug or add logs in `onBindViewHolder()` to print used data, you will see it's updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need to set the adapter again to update elements.

Instead as you were trying to do, you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` but to do that you have to update the adpater's data first, here is a good way to do that:

**1-**

add this method to your adapter

```
public void updateData(final ArrayList<ArrayList<StationArrivalPOJO>> stationArrivalPOJO ) {
        mStationPojoList= new ArrayList<>();
        mStationPojoList.addAll(stationArrivalPOJO);
    }
```

**2-**

in your `Nearby_ViewPager_Stations` inside `addAdapter`, do the following:

```
  stationArrivalPOJO.addAll(resultData);
  mAdapter.updateData(stationArrivalPOJO); // updating adapter's data
  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //notifying the adapter
```

Comment: I tried as you said. But still it is not updating data

Comment: Impossible!, are sure you passed the correct new data, I mean that before calling `mAdapter.updateData(stationArrivalPOJO);`  are you sure that `stationArrivalPOJO` has new data or not? have you debugged the code?

Comment: These are the lines I added:                                         stationArrivalPOJO.clear();
        stationArrivalPOJO.addAll(resultData);

        Adapter_recyclerView view = new Adapter_recyclerView();
        view.updateData(stationArrivalPOJO);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I have read your code!, please debug the code and make sure that `resultData` contains new data and hence `stationArrivalPOJO` contains new data

Comment: Yes. resultData is getting new data. And i printed the data in updateData() in adapter class. I got the new data in adapter class also

Comment: I have no idea what could the problem be!, I guess there is something wrong with adapter, but this way of sending updated data to the adapter, and it has been sent as you say.

Comment: Why you don't use the `getItemId()` in the adapter?

Comment: Finally !!!! The problem is not with adapter. I am actually dynamically adding layout in onBindViewHolder(). That layout is not getting updated with new values. Thank you so much for helping me trace my problem.

Comment: @Sindhu `onBindViewHolder` is part of your adapter, Always the problem is in adapter :D, you're welcome :), please accept the answer for the other people to know the solution of the question's problem

Comment: Edit your answer stating that problem is in my adapter bindViewHolder(). Then i will accept it : )

Comment: @Sindhu, I don't really undersatnds what you did, It's better for you to edit it and provide the solution you did (at the bottom of my answer) and you I will accept your edit!

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Don't store your adapter in a property of your activity/fragment. Always call and cast from `mRecyclerView.getAdapter()`

I had the same issue.
All people only say is use notifyDataSetChanged() and that should do it (some might argue on using the notifyItem* ones, I'd say it depends)

Just fixed it thanks to your comments on the accepted answer (even when is not the correct one)

Yes, notifyDataSetChanged() is being called on my adapter, but is not the correct adapter to update.
I have a recycler with around 500 items being filtered, I can see that the new items list is being reduced to 10 items, but the UI was still showing all of the items.
[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42366139/notifydatasetchanged-does-not-update-my-recycler-view#comment71886334_42366823) made me question if mine was being called, so I put some logs and well, I saw that it was still using the original 500 items list even after I got the logs that the adapter had a new list with just 10.

Well, this was caused by having a property in my fragment and updating that adapter.

```java
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

onCreateView() {
    // Retrieve data and more code
    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(data);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

filter(String txt) {
    // Here the adapter handles filtering the list
    // and calling notifyDataSetChanged()
    mAdapter.filter(query);
}
```

Now it's like this and is working

```java
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

onCreateView() {
    // Retrieve data and more code
    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(data));
}

filter(String txt) {
    // Here the adapter handles filtering the list
    // and calling notifyDataSetChanged()
    ((MyRecyclerViewAdapter)mRecyclerView.getAdapter()).filter(query)
}
```

> I'd say you don't have to accept an answer if it didn't help resolve your issue.
>  And if you solved it yourself you can answer your own question and accept your own answer.